# Component dynamic calculation of percentage based on value periodically inputted to component (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, components

I was wondering if there is a better way to perform a calculation on Angular component (than what I am doing now), based on a value inputted to a component.

What I am doing now is on a component I am calling a method like so:

```
<ng-container>
  calculatePercentage(stock.name, stock.paid, stock.quantity, stock.currentPrice)%
</ng-container>
```

It's an app that shows how much your stock is worth at any given moment.

On a controller I have a method:

```
calculatePercentage(stock.name, stock.paid, stock.quantity, stock.currentPrice) {
  ...
  return value;
}
```

The component gets a recent price of the stock via API and returns a value like -1% or 1% to show a user whether or not they're making or losing money on a particular investment.

*Problem:*
When I throw `console.log` to this method I see that it's firing infinitely even if no updated values are provided to perform a calculation. So that tells me this is not a way to do it.

What is the best way to do this type of calculation. It should be triggered only if new values are provided. Do I have to use Angular Pipes?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: you can use rxjs operators distinctUntilChanged: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged, but I think you has a bad desing in your app. In general functions in .hml must be avoided, it's better calculate in the .ts and use an auxiliar variable (or if you has an array, map the array adding a new property) but it's difficult for me know your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is normal behavior of change detection mechanism. You can change the component's detection strategy to OnPush and yes, I'd use [PercentagePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe)

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Comment: Thank you @ihorbond. I rewrote everything using a custom pipe.